# Rendering shapes in actual sizes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, size

I'm thinking about using JavaScript to present a Multiple Object Tracking task as part of a greater online experiment.  The issue is that I need to specify objects (in this case, moving balls) in actual sizes (mm, in, etc.) so that they appear at a consistent, real size across participants (or monitors with varying resolutions).

Java has a getNormalizingTransform() method that meets this goal.  Does JavaScript have something equivalent to this?  Or more generally, is there a way to render objects in JavaScript so that they appear to be the same size across screens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use absolute CSS units like cm, mm, or in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript itself does not render. Browsers render pages, where generally the content is defined in HTML, the style rules are defined in CSS, and javascript is used to manipulate them, and provide client side scripting.

What you are asking can be done with CSS, or indirectly with javascript, by specifying CSS rules...

```
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html
```

Assuming you have an element with an ID `myElement`...

```
<div id="myElement">test div</div>
```

In css...

```
#myElement{
    width: 100mm;
    height: 10mm;
}
```

Or in javascript...

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.width = "100mm"
```

Comment: Okay, that's probably why searching Google with the term "JavaScript" turned up nothing.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, worth noting that it is the browser's responsibility to set the size of elements, so implementation might vary from browser to browser, and indeed the browser might not be accurately informed of the screen size. For example, if a computer is plugged into a projector, there could be the same content mirrored in different sizes, and it is common for the OS to guess the approximate scale of a pixel, and sometimes people who care about it, might set it accurately.